# In dolphindb,I called view function in the startup script (startup.dos), which did not take effect，why?

Tags: dolphindb

In dolphindb,I called view function in the startup script (startup.dos), which did not take effect，why?

And I found this error message is serve log : "Exception was raised when running the script file [xxx]:Syntax ERROR : Can't recognize the token func.

Answer (score 0):

It's my fault. I checked the view function again. It's really that I accidentally deleted it. If I add it back, the result is in line with expectations.